# Filling array with next empty space?

Tags: java, arrays, increment

Here are my two classes Country and Countries. I am doing questions from online as extra practice.

I need to:
-Add a method to Countries - addCountry(String name, String capital, int population - Which fills in the element by nextFreeCountry and increments nextFreeCountry

Can somebody provide some help? I am struggling to understand how to fill in the element by nextFreeCountry.

Country:

```
public class Country {

    private String name;
    private String capital;
    private int population;
```

Constructor to add the name capital and population

```
    public Country(String name, String capital, int population) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
        this.population = population;
    }
```

Get name method

```
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name = " + getName() + " Capital = " + getCapital() + " Population = " + getPopulation();
    }
}
```

Countries:

```
class Countries {
```

Creating an array of Country called countries

```
    private Country[] countries;
    private int nextFreeCountry = 0;
```

Setting the size for the array

```
    public Countries(int size) {
        countries = new Country[size];
    }
```

addCountry method

```
    public void addCountry(String name, String capital, int population) {
        countries[nextFreeCountry] = 
        nextFreeCountry++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As `countries` array hold `Country` objects, so create a new object and put it in array. Something like this:

```
public void addCountry(String name, String capital, int population) {
    countries[nextFreeCountry] = new Country(name,capital,population);
    nextFreeCountry++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a new country to the array which you are not doing at the moment. Like so:

```
public void addCountry(String name, String capital, int population) {
        countries[nextFreeCountry] = new Country(name, capital, population);
        nextFreeCountry++;
}
```

Alternatively just pass a Country to the method like this:

```
public void addCountry(Country country) {
            countries[nextFreeCountry] = country;
            nextFreeCountry++;
}
```

You may also be better off using an ArrayList rather than an array so you dont have to worry about the array index being out of bounds etc.